# Why does PHP not receive POST data sent via AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've seen this many times before on Stack Overflow and other websites, but none of the previous posts seem to be helping.

Assume the following HTML code:

```
<input maxlength="50" size="50" id="searchTxt" />
```

And assume the following AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tdat.php",
    data: {userresponse: $('#searchTxt').val()},
    success: function(){
        $('#searchTxt').val("")
    }
})
```

What *should* happen is that the data "userresponse" gets posted to the server, having the value of whatever is inside the input box, and then the input in the box is emptied.

Later, I have the following PHP code in tdat.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['userresponse'])){
        $userResponsePHP = $_POST['userresponse'];
        switch($userResponsePHP){
            case "yes":
            echo "alert(\"hi\")";
            break;
        case "no":
            echo "alert(\"negative!\")";
            break;
        default:
            echo "alert(\"nope.\")";
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

The PHP does not respond, even if the AJAX call works perfectly. PHP does not even receive the value of "userresponse". I have checked the file paths, localhost connection, adding quotes to "userresponse", and practically all other minor issues stated in other threads, but the problem persists. *The AJAX call clears the value of searchTxt, thus it is a successful send. No errors are shown in the console*. Why is this so?

Comment: try instead of `isset($_POST['userresponse'])` use `!empty($_POST['userresponse'])`

Comment: I had same problem, I replaced key  userresponse with "userresponse", try

Comment: Already read about that, and tried it. Nothing changed

Comment: what errors do you have in the console?

Comment: No error, as I stated above

Comment: can you post a printscreen with the xhr header, the bottom part of it?

Comment: Use post man for chrome or fiddler tool or similar tools and send a post request manually and check your php so you can rule out which part of your code is wrong.

Comment: @Hundotte do you even know what a xhr is?

Comment: Please make some clarifications: 
1.When the ajax call is triggered.

Comment: Does the content of `<input>` go away on POST ? If so the problem is you have to use `alert()` function within the `<script>` tag or the php script should be embedded in the script tag

Comment: `error: function(){
        alert('error in response')
    }` can you have something like this after success

Comment: Modify your *ajax* function first as follows:

`success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
    $('#searchTxt').val("");
}`

then share the console result.

Comment: error: function(){ alert('error in response') } does not work, returns error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

Comment: console.log(res) does not return anything, and the searchTxt does not clear

Comment: @Hundotte how do you tirgger the ajax call?

Comment: no, but the console.log(res) is in front of the $('#searchTxt').val("")

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tdat.php",
    data: {userresponse: $('#searchTxt').val()},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.message);
        $('#searchTxt').val("");
    }
})
```

php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if(isset($_POST['userresponse'])){
        $userResponsePHP = $_POST['userresponse'];
        switch($userResponsePHP){
            case "yes":
            echo json_encode(["message"=>"hi"]);
            break;
        case "no":
            echo json_encode(["message"=>"negative"]);
            break;
        default:
            echo json_encode(["message"=>"nope"]);

            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Note: if the page is refreshing you aren't doing any ajax

Comment: i think you need to set `dataType:'json'`

Comment: @guradio jquery will take care of that

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet works, however it's generally recommended not to use eval I'm using eval in this case because you have the JavaScript alert function on the server-side (in the PHP).  What you should do is echo the text and then call the alert function on the Javascript side.  However, in the interest of changing as little as possible to your code I'm leaving it as is and only making changes in the JavaScript.

2 things to make note of in this example I initialize the text box with one of your accepted values 'yes'.  Of course you can change this so the ajax call is made on say a button click (wasn't sure what your use case was)

One small thing you forgot was to read in the **data** parameter in the success callback.

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#searchTxt').val("yes");
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "tdat.php",
           data: {userresponse: $('#searchTxt').val()},
           success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              eval(data);
              $('#searchTxt').val("")
           }
        })
    });
</script>
<input maxlength="50" size="50" id="searchTxt" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your *ajax* function first as follows:

```
$('#searchTxt').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tdat.php",
        data: {userresponse: $('#searchTxt').val()},
        success: function(res){
            $('#searchTxt').val("");
            console.log(res);
        }
     });
 });
```

On the change event of *searchTxt* your ajax call will be executed and then check the console.

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: why do you have html in your php ?,do you have 2 separate files one with the ajax and one with the php?,how do you trigger your ajax?